# PDF Generation works on Local Environment but not on Production (Puppeteer)

Tags: reactjs, puppeteer, pdf-generation

I have developed a web application using react and I am using puppeteer to generate a PDF, everything works perfectly in local environment on my computer but when I deploy it to AWS EC2 it doesn't work, the only error I am getting is 500 Internal Server Error.

```
app.get('/download-pdf/:page', async (req, res) => {
  const { page } = req.params;
  const { slider1, slider2, slider3, email, recipientName } = req.query;

  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless:"true" });
    const pageInstance = await browser.newPage();
    await pageInstance.goto(`http://localhost:3000/pages/${page}.html?slider1=${slider1}&slider2=${slider2}&slider3=${slider3}`);
    await pageInstance.waitForTimeout(2000);
    const pdfBuffer = await pageInstance.pdf({ format: 'A3' }).catch(error => {
      console.error('Error generating PDF:', error);
      throw error; // Rethrow the error to be caught in the outer try-catch block
    });
        
    await browser.close();

    // Send the PDF via email if email is provided
    if (email) {
      await sendPdfByEmailApi(email, pdfBuffer, recipientName || "User", page);
    }

    // Set headers before sending the response
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
    res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', `attachment; filename=${page}.pdf`);
    res.send(pdfBuffer);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error generating PDF:', error);
    res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
  }
}); ⁠
```

I tried looking for articles and found out that some dependencies could be missing and I did download the dependencies and it worked and I had to restart the server due to some issues and now it's not working again even after I try the earlier solutions I came across.

Comment: 500 internal server error means you should look at your server logs to see what the actual stack trace was. Once you have it, please post it here--that's the main problem to focus on solving.